# Browse through nodes in XmlNodeList (vb.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlnodelist

I can't find in the documentation how to "browse" through the nodes that I already have in XmlNodeList.

Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
  <tu changedate="20180509T145123Z" creationdate="20180509T145123Z" >
    <prop type="aligned">no</prop>
    <prop type="x-context">320920</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="en-gb">
      <seg>Hello1</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="es">
      <seg>Hola1</seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>
  <tu changedate="20180509T145216Z" creationdate="20180509T145216Z" >
    <prop type="aligned">no</prop>
    <prop type="x-context">325152</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="en-gb">
      <seg>Hello2</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="es">
      <seg>Hola2</seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>
</tmx>
```

I am trying to run through the different nodes in each /tu to load that to a DB. Should be simple but I am struggling with the syntax.

So far I have this:

```
Dim tmxfile As String = "d:\Documents\Desktop\myxml.xml"
        Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument
        xmldoc.Load(tmxfile)

        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//tu")

        For node = 0 To nodes.Count - 1
            Dim x = nodes.Item(node).SelectNodes("/seg")

            MsgBox(x.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
```

What I am trying to achieve is to show each /seg in //tu. The first part of the code is fine as if I loop through node with innerxml or innertext I see the actual elements of XML, but I am struggling to get the specified elements on those nodes.

Any guidance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about using LINQ-to-XML? Moreover, VB has great feature - [XML Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/xml-literals-overview)!

Comment: Try `//seg` or `/tuv/seg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd use [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/bb387063(v=vs.110)) instead of XmlDocument, you could use unique VB's feature - [XML Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/xml-literals-overview):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim xml =
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
    <tu changedate="20180509T145123Z" creationdate="20180509T145123Z">
        <prop type="aligned">no</prop>
        <prop type="x-context">320920</prop>
        <tuv xml:lang="en-gb">
            <seg>Hello1</seg>
        </tuv>
        <tuv xml:lang="es">
            <seg>Hola1</seg>
        </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu changedate="20180509T145216Z" creationdate="20180509T145216Z">
        <prop type="aligned">no</prop>
        <prop type="x-context">325152</prop>
        <tuv xml:lang="en-gb">
            <seg>Hello2</seg>
        </tuv>
        <tuv xml:lang="es">
            <seg>Hola2</seg>
        </tuv>
    </tu>
</tmx>

    xml.AddFirst(New XDocumentType("tmx", "SYSTEM", "tmx14.dtd", ""))

    ' All <tu> elements
    Dim tus = xml.<tmx>.<tu>

    For Each tu In tus
        Dim seg = tu.<tuv>.<seg>
        Console.WriteLine(seg.Value)
    Next

    Console.ReadKey(True)

End Sub
```

Comment: BTW, how would you access the different elements with properties, for example if I want to read the value of <prop type="x-context"> ?

Comment: @daviddgz Say, you have element: `Dim xml = <prop type="x-context">Some Value</prop>`. Then, to get value: `Dim value = xml.Value`. To get attribute: `Dim attr = xml.@type`. If attribute has dot or dash (say, `type-name` or `type.name`), then use brackets: `Dim attr = xml.<type-name>` or `Dim attr = xml.@<type.name>`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnyL I understand what you are saying, but in the context of my full XML, I don't see a way of specifying in the code I want to read the element value of `<prop type="x-context">325152</prop>` and not any other `<prop>` element. Let's say I have 10 `<prop>` elements in the XML but I only want to read the value of the ones with the attribute `type="x-context"`. I've been browsing the documentation and I can't find any examples of how to do that unfortunately.

Comment: @daviddgz You just need to filter it out. Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6M92wk) with sample code. Also, you can play in [try.dot.net](https://try.dot.net).